# How many db-users should I create?

Tags: mysql

guys!

I need to ask you a question... I'm mew in programming business and if this question seems silly, please indulge me.
I have a little site where people have to register in order to post something. So I register every user in the database. I log into the db with:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname="MY-DB", "My-USER", "My-password");
```

The question is: when I log into the databse to do whatever operation I need (select, update, delete, insert) how many users ("MY-USER") should I create to login to the db ? Should I create one db-user for every users that registers on my site, or one one single user is enough to do the operations ?
Thanks.

Comment: One is usually enough, for most situations (I mean with the exception of `root`). You should provide more details about why you think more users are needed (some special security issue maybe ?), perhaps we can figure out an answer that way.

Comment: Two users. One is "root" user with all privileges and one is for your site to get/update data. The root user is normally created automatically.

Comment: I don't see any particular security issue right now. The site doesn't create databases or tables by its own.

Answer (score 1):

In normal situations you should have additionally to a root user, which can create new databases and add new users, you should create one user per application which is accessing the database, so that a bug in one application wouldn't affect another.

In your case this means to have 1 additional user for your web application which has all permissions on one mysql-database and can create the necessary tables as well as read / modify data in those.

You should not use mysql as your user manager, instead create a table with the users, their (hashed) passwords, ... and manage them in your application.

Comment: Thanks. One user except the root is enough. That makes it easier.